# "It is important to recognise the interdependence between individual, culturally formed actions and the state of cultural integration." meaning

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> **It is important to recognise the interdependence between
> individual, culturally formed actions and the state of cultural
> integration.** People work within the forms provided by the
> cultural patterns that they have internalised, however
> contradictory these may be. Ideas are worked out as logical
> implications or consequences of other accepted ideas, and it is in
> this way that cultural innovations and discoveries are possible.
> New ideas are discovered through logical reasoning, but such
> discoveries are inherent in and integral to the conceptual system
> and are made possible only because of the acceptance of its
> premises. For example, the discoveries of new prime numbers
> are ‘real’ consequences of the particular number system employed.
> Thus, cultural ideas show ‘advances’ and ‘developments’
> because they are outgrowths of previous ideas. The cumulative work of many individuals produces a corpus of
> knowledge within which certain ‘discoveries’ become possible
> or more likely. Such discoveries are ‘ripe’ and could not have
> occurred earlier and are also likely to be made simultaneously
> by numbers of individuals.

What does this bold sentence mean? I think that in this paragraph the subject is old accepted thoughts lead to evolution of new ideas. So this bold sentence must be associated with the subject. But I can't match between the bold sentence and the subject. Please explain "individual, culturally formed actions", "the stand of cultural integration", and "why these are the state of interdependence" to me easily with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The full quote is here.
https://books.google.com/books?id=48oTF_mJvtEC&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false

Understanding the sentence probably depends on the full context.

Let's try removing a few words:

> It is important to recognise the interdependence between individual actions and the culture.

Ok.

Delving into the phrase "the state of cultural integration", he is proposing that the culture can be contradictory, and have inconsistencies within it.  The level of integration would refer to the extent of those contradictions. How "integrated" is the culture.

It's hard to resist thinking that these types of texts are purposefully obfuscated. The author's main goal is not to clearly express an important and real idea.  Rather, it's to integrate himself within the cultural ethos. There, I'm doing it also.

If you follow the preceding and following paragraphs of the book, and treat this one sentence like the simplified version just mentioned, then it should be enough.